# Cómo ocultar filas que se mostraron de uno en uno- jquery.?

Tags: jquery, css, html5, grid

Tengo una sección de bloques que se muestran 4 en cada una de las filas. Con el botón **LOAD MORE** se mostrará otra fila con 4 bloques y así hasta que muestre todos los bloques.

Cómo podría hacer que cuando ya están todas las filas mostradas, se puedan ocultar todos pero que se mantenga siempre visible la primera fila superior como estaba al inicio.

Lo que tengo al momento es que se muestran bien como lo necesito pero al dar click en **VIEW LESS** se ocultan todos incluyendo la primera fila.
El funcionamiento es con jquery y se da con dos botones que se muestran y ocultan según se muestren/oculten las filas con bloques. Uno de **LOAD MORE** y otro con **VIEW LESS**

Esto es lo que tengo al momento:

```js
$('.load-more').click(function() {
    var resources = $('.post-container:not(.show)');

    if(resources.length > 0 && resources.length <= 4) {
        $('.post-container:not(.show)').addClass('show');
        $('.content-library-btn-container .load-more').hide();
        $('.content-library-btn-container .view-less').show();
    } else if(resources.length > 0) {
        $('.post-container:not(.show):lt(4)').addClass('show');
        $('.content-library-btn-container .view-less').hide();
        
    }
});

$('.view-less').click(function() {
    var resources = $('.post-container.show');

    if(resources.length > 0 && resources.length >= 4) {
        $('.post-container.show').removeClass('show');
    } else if(resources.length < 0) {
        $('.post-container.show:lt(4)').removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

```css
.content-library-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap; }
    .content-library-wrapper .show {
      display: -webkit-box !important;
      display: -ms-flexbox !important;
      display: flex !important; }
    .content-library-wrapper .post-container {
      width: calc( (100% / 4) - 20px);
      margin: 0 10px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      position: relative;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-flow: column;
              flex-flow: column;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      display: none; }
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .content-library-wrapper .post-container {
          width: calc( (100% / 2) - 20px); 
    } 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.content-library-wrapper .post-container {
  width: 100%; } 
}


      .content-library-wrapper .post-container .post-content {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5;
        border-top: 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
        padding: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column; 
}


  .content-library-btn-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .content-library-btn-container {
        margin-top: 0; } }
    .content-library-btn-container .cta-outline {
      background-color:gold;
        padding: 20px;
}

.view-less {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-library-wrapper">
    <div class="post-container show">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div><!--/.post-excerpt-->
            <a href="#0">READ </a>
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-container-->
    <div class="post-container show">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div><!--/.post-excerpt-->
            <a href="#0">READ </a>
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-container-->
    <div class="post-container show">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div><!--/.post-excerpt-->
            <a href="#0">READ </a>
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-container-->
    <div class="post-container show">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div><!--/.post-excerpt-->
            <a href="#0">READ </a>
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-container-->
    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div><!--/.post-excerpt-->
            <a href="#0">READ </a>
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-container-->
    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div><!--/.post-excerpt-->
            <a href="#0">READ </a>
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-container-->
    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div><!--/.post-excerpt-->
            <a href="#0">READ </a>
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-container-->
    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div><!--/.post-excerpt-->
            <a href="#0">READ </a>
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-container-->
    <div class="post-container">
        <div class="post-content">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div><!--/.post-excerpt-->
            <a href="#0">READ </a>
        </div><!--/.post-content-->
    </div><!--/.post-container-->
                    
</div><!--/.content-library-wrapper-->

<div class="content-library-btn-container">
   <a href="#0" class="cta-outline load-more">LOAD MORE</a>
    <a href="#0" class="cta-outline view-less">VIEW LESS</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Rápidamente se me ocurre que con el botón View Less recargues la página, o la vista o la sección, así te muestra sólo los primeros 4 bloques.

Comment: Quizá te sirva el selector :first-child, con el que al menos podrías volver a mostrar el primero tras ocultar todos. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child